# Decomposition of iron(III) acetate?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment, aqueous-solution

[I recently asked about the synthesis of iron (III) acetate.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7574/can-i-synthesize-iron-acetate-like-this) I want a rather concentrated solution to use as a calligraphy ink (which will be dissolved in alcohol/water). Will it be okay to heat the solution of iron(III) acetate, hydrogen peroxide, acetic acid, and water to evaporate all of the other reagents? That is, will heat cause the decomposition of the iron acetate?

Comment: I don't think it should be a problem.  Acetate is a stable ion. Iron(III)(or ferric)  ions are also quite stable. Quick wikipedia check shows its stable- it would be no good as a ferric ion test if the ferric ion decomposed to ferrous Fe(II) ions. Wiki lists it as dye.

Comment: @user2617804 Would you like to make an answer out of that comment, with links to the sources?

Answer (score 2):

Iron(III) acetate will be stable under these conditions. According to this [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01981811), thermal decomposition to iron oxide only starts at 423 K (150 °C). Heating iron and acetic acid together with an oxidation agent (oxygen from air or, like in your case, $\ce{H2O2}$) is actually a suitable way to prepare iron acetate dyes ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron%28III%29_acetate)).